# Silverlight 4 - Reporting Services viewer

Tags: silverlight-4.0, reporting-services, viewer

Does anyone know of an out of the box or decent **free** third party reporting services viewer for Silverlight 4?

From what I can determine Silverlight 4 still doesn't have an out of the box viewer. Perhaps there is one on the way from Microsoft?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, there isn't one at the moment, although a lot of people would love there to be one.  My advice to anyone who asks this question is to simply output the report as a PDF on the server, and host it in an Iframe overlayed on your application (or hosted in the WebBrowser control if running outside the browser).  I include links to an article I've written on the topic, and the code associated with my book (that also covers this topic, but also includes support for OOB) in this similar question: [Show pdf inside silverlight application. PDF to XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770952/show-pdf-inside-silverlight-application-pdf-to-xaml/4772963#4772963).

Hope this helps...

Chris Anderson

Answer (score 0):

There is no free viewer I am aware of, but commercially you have this - http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/Silverlight-Viewer-for-Reporting-Services.aspx